# create a new dataframe column using the data from other column on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
    Name        Default Expression    Override Expression 
0   AACT_NAM        pystr                   pyint
1   ACCT_CCY        pystr
2   ACCT_TYP        pystr
```

I want to create a column, `_faker_method_` that would contain specially transformed data by checking if `Override Expression` has value and use it, if there is some value or
use `Default Expression` column if there is no value.

I tried to do like this

```
df['_faker_invocation_'] = df['Override Expression'].apply(lambda x: render_faker_expresison(df['Name'], x) if x else df['Default Expression'])
```

But logs should me that the function `render_faker_expression` recieves whole column with index (and thus it fails in my app)

```
0                           ACCT_NAM
1                           ACCT_CCY
2                           ACCT_TYP
```

How to perform the action I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sharing `render_faker_expression` (or at least its signature) which makes it hard to pin down the problem. But since it seems to expect a scalar value instead of a series, I guess you want to apply your lambda function row-wise:

```
df['_faker_invocation_'] = df.apply(lambda row: render_faker_expresison(row['Name'], row['Override Expression'])
                                                if row['Override Expression']
                                                else row['Default Expression'], axis=1)
```

With the following dummy function:

```
def render_faker_expresison(n, x):
    return x + "_fake_" + n
```

This gives us:

```
        Name Default Expression Override Expression   _faker_invocation_
ID                                                                      
0   AACT_NAM              pystr               pyint  pyint_fake_AACT_NAM
1   ACCT_CCY              pystr                None                pystr
2   ACCT_TYP              pystr                None                pystr
```

Comment: For some reason it always passes `nan` as a second parameter of `render_faker_expression`. Could it be due to me loading dataframe from excel?

Comment: That would mean `row['Override Expression']` is always nan. Check for typos (the function had a typo in your question that made it into my answer for instance), column names and content, parentheses...

Comment: I guess I can use `pandas.isnull` in condition then